# Trouble when entry conditions ichimoku

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

below is my problem I have, I'm trying to make this script so when the price closes above both the "cloud_lower" and the "leadLine1", however I think my problem is when they are plotted they are plotted with an "offset=(displacement -1)" how can I add this into my entry conditions as you can only use offset when plotting.

Thanks in advance!

```
//Lower calc
donchian(len) => math.avg(ta.lowest(len), ta.highest(len))
displacement = input.int(26, minval=1, title="Lagging Span")
//Upper calc
conversionPeriods = 9
basePeriods = 26
conversionLine = donchian(conversionPeriods)
baseLine = donchian(basePeriods)

//Plotting cloud uppert for price action
leadLine1 = math.avg(conversionLine, baseLine)
plot(leadLine1, color=#000000, title ="CloudUpper",offset=displacement-1)  //offset=displacement-1


//Plotting cloud Lower for price action
Cloud_Lower = 52
cloud_lower = donchian(Cloud_Lower)
plot(cloud_lower, color=#ff00aa, title ="Cloud lower",offset=displacement-1)


//entry conditions
price_above_Cloud_Lower = close[1] > donchian(Cloud_Lower)
exitcond = close[1] < donchian(Cloud_Lower)

price_above_Cloud_upper = close[1] > math.avg(conversionLine, baseLine)


//conversion and baseline
condition_conversion_baseline = baseLine > conversionLine 

//entry
if cloud_lower and price_above_Cloud_upper and condition_conversion_baseline
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, comment="Long Entry")
 
if cloud_lower
    strategy.close("Long", comment="Long Exit")
```

Ive tried heaps of different functions to try and project the "cloud_lower" and the "leadLine1" 25 bars forward but I cant seem to get it.